# Is there a special word in Okinawa for "cheers" / "乾杯{かんぱい}"?

Tags: ryukyuan-languages

Another traveller in my guesthouse in Naha thinks his local friends taught him a special local word for "cheers", that might sound like "kuri" or "kali".

But the Okinawan owner of the guesthouse doesn't know this word. He doesn't speak Okinawan fluently but he knows lots of words as both his parents were speakers and he's in his 50s.

In any case, I don't mind if it's a word from ウチナーグチ or just modern local slang used by young people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be「カリーサビラ」 or 「カリー」 for short.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFyBfvjgpxk

http://hougen.ajima.jp/hougen.php?lid=420

Comment: It also has a nice little [entry in "JLECT"](http://www.jlect.com/entry/732/karii/) which tells you what Japanese words it's related to.